# ImageView.getX() получаю всегда нулевое значение

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Добрый вечер!

Суть проблемы заключается в том что при выполнение этого кода:

```
float x = imageCell[5][5].getX();
float y = imageCell[5][5].getY();
int xx = Math.round(x);
int yy = Math.round(y);
textview.setText(String.valueOf(xx+" " + yy));
```

Что я делаю не так?

Пытаюсь получить координаты элемента `ImageView` на экране, но как бы я не делал всегда получаю значение ноль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, что Вы пытаетесь получить данное значение в методе `onCreate(...)` активити и вполне справедливо получаете ноль, так как во время выполнения данного метода виджеты еще не были отрисованы и все их числовые характеристики, связанные с расположением и размерами будут нулевыми.

Вышеприведенное утверждение легко проверить следующим образом:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "mImageView.getX(): " + mImageView.getX());
    }
});
```

В данном случае, при нажатии на `ImageView`, Вы получите корректное значение.

Отследить *окончание отрисовки* `View` можно с помощью `OnGlobalLayoutListener` следующим образом:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener mOnGlobalLayoutListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        mOnGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "mImageView.getX(): " + mImageView.getX());
                mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener);
            }
        };

        mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе onCreate   setContentView(R.layout.game_map);  и затем вызываю метод который получает координаты.

Comment: Вы правы, он не успевает получит координаты ещё не отрисованного элемента.

Comment: Проверил, ваш способ через кнопку. Координаты х получает, а вот Y  выдаёт ноль. У меня таблица, возможно игрик координату нужно получать не самого элемента внтури строки, а игрик координаты самой строки?

Comment: @Александр, Я не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос так как не знаю, что и как у Вас там организовано.

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо большое за подсказку с отрисовкой.